How to collect the data and generate a report with the below details?
I am writing a fairly straightforward application for my thesis project where the goal is to have balance sheet and income statement data stored in the system and to generate "reports" about those with specified KPIs.
I will share the data model with you to have an overview of what I am working on.
My current Data Model
The balance sheets and the income statements are stored in a way that there is a parent record which describes the financial statement itself (which enterprise it is for and which period of what fiscal year the data describes). From this the reports would be generated basically the same way, for a specific period of a fiscal year and for a specific enterprise.
The reports are also stored in similar ways, however when storing the records of a report I actually store a formal overview of a KPI in them, that is referenced in the column.
The KPI itself has a formula stored as string, and the parameters it uses are being stored in another table, but these parameters are completely formal, the value of them should be queried during a calculation procedure.
My ask would be is someone could kindly assist me in puzzling together a procedure in PL/SQL (the whole database is Oracle based) to calculate a record of a report based on data.
For now I am just trying to figure out a way to get the exact data to be handed over to the formula and executed in a procedure but it is too complicated for me, I did not think this would be such a challenge.
I have an example record that should sum up my problem and the calculation method of this.
So lets say my generated report is for TEST Corp. and I want to calculate a RoE on the report for 2024 Q1.
With this there would be a report generated for the exact same period with the exact same enterprise, and there would be a record on among the report_records which would mention the KPI: RoE.
In the KPI table RoE would store the following formula: "Net Income / Stakeholder's Equity".
The two parameters would be stored in the KPI params table as such:
'RoE' as Foreign Key KPI - 'Net Income' as name of record needed - 'IS' as Income Statement.
'RoE' as Foreign Key KPI - Stakeholder's Equity as name of Record needed - 'BS' as Balance Sheet which the record is found on.
I think with this all the data is ready to be calculated, however I am completeley lost as to how I could code this on a procedure, since it is more complex than most of the things I have encountered so far.
The value of a report_record would be calculated using the stored formula in the referenced KPI record.
I would like to ask for someones assistance regarding this and any kind of help or maybe modification suggestions would be most welcome.

Hi , could you please give us more information like the Table structure , sample data and expected output..

Hi @HimanshuKandpal! Will do this in separate comments since it would be too long.
Thank you very much for taking a look into it. :)
This link image contains all the table structure that are currently in the application. If you would like the creation scripts, I can also supply those as well.

@HimanshuKandpal,
I would imagine that a procedure like this should do the job but I'm not sure:
PROCEDURE EEH_SP_CALCULATE_RECORD(p_recordseq IN EEH_REPORT_RECORDS.recordseq%TYPE,
p_success OUT INT,
p_error OUT INT,
p_error_msg OUT VARCHAR2);
It gets the id of a record that should be calculated, and the record contains a reference to the KPI itself, which contains the calculation formula and references the parameters from the BalSheet or the IncStatement.

@HimanshuKandpal
If I want to calculate a RoE for example, with a Net Income of 100000 (stored among Income Statement records) and the Stakeholder's Equity (stored among Balsheet records) at 100000 then the calculation should be 100000 / 100000, so the stored value of a report record should be 1 exactly.
I'm not sure if this clarifies anything, but if you need any more info, just hit me up, I would appreciate the help very much!

is there a way you could give us a simple table structure, with sample data and the expected output , it will be very time consuming to understand from the diagram which you shared .
